# Error integreting webhook adyen API in java spring backend, Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring, post, webhooks, adyen

Hello i am trying to implements adyen webhook, but i recived error because i can't mapping they're request into an object.

How can i recive a call 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded and mapping into an object with java spring?

````
RequestMapping(value = "/webhooks/notifications", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
    public Response webhooks(Map<String, Object>  notificationRequest) throws Exception{
        try {
            try {
            //notificationRequest.get(notificationRequest);
                    
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    NotificationRequestDTO notification = mapper.convertValue(notificationRequest, NotificationRequestDTO.class);
                    adyenService.webhooks(notification);
                 
                return Response.ok("accepted").build();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Errore durante la richiesta di webhooks  adyen", ex);
                return Response.serverError(ex.getMessage()).build();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error purchase: {}", new Object[] { ex.getMessage() });
            return Response.serverError(ex.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }```

i have tried multiple solution with @RequestBody or @RequestParam or without annotaion, but bothing works, i can recive data only using Map but then objectmapper failed to transform into the object we need.

another example is
````

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webhooks/notifications", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public Response webhooks( NotificationRequestDTO notificationRequest) throws Exception{
    try {
        try {
        //notificationRequest.get(notificationRequest);
                
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                NotificationRequestDTO notification = mapper.convertValue(notificationRequest, NotificationRequestDTO.class);
                adyenService.webhooks(notification);
             
            return Response.ok("accepted").build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Errore durante la richiesta di webhooks  adyen", ex);
            return Response.serverError(ex.getMessage()).build();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error purchase: {}", new Object[] { ex.getMessage() });
        return Response.serverError(ex.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

```
the error is {"code":"500","entity":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported"}
```

Comment: Why do you consume `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE`? The webhook payload is JSON

Comment: because i got error "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported when they call me

Comment: try to remove `consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})` and add `@RequestBody` to the signature in your second example

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Same error? Which version of the Java library are you using? You can also take a look at the webhook in the Java Sample app https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-java-spring-online-payments/blob/main/checkout-example/src/main/java/com/adyen/checkout/api/WebhookResource.java

Comment: i tried same of that example and now i have a different error: Could not read JSON: Problem deserializing 'setterless' property 'notificationItems': get method returned null\n at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 3, column: 24] (through reference chain: com.adyen.model.notification.NotificationRequest[\"notificationItems\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Problem deserializing 'setterless' property 'notificationItems': get method returned null\n at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream

Comment: same error again"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Comment: ok, I think you use Adyen Java v19.0.0 (just released) which is not compatible with Jackson (used by Spring). Use v18.1.3 instead